# How to do update in AWS Dynamo DB using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-dynamodb

I have written this function to do update in dynamo table

```
const updateTask = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { existingTaskText,updatedTaskText } = req.body;
    console.log(existingTaskText,updatedTaskText );
    UPDATE({
      TableName: "todos",
      Key:{ task: existingTaskText},
      UpdateExpression:"set task = :task",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {":task": updatedTaskText},
    });
    res.status(200).json({ data: "this is controller" });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

this is calling UPDATE

```
const UPDATE = async (payload) => {
  try {
    console.log(payload);
    const updateDoc = await dbClient
      .update({
        TableName: payload.TableName,
        Key: payload.Key,
        UpdateExpression: payload.UpdateExpression,
        ExpressionAttributeNames:payload.ExpressionAttributeNames,
        ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW",
      })
      .promise();
    console.log(updateDoc);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

When I am testing this in postman, I am getting this error

```
ValidationException: Invalid UpdateExpression: An expression attribute value used in expression is not defined; attribute value: :task
```

this is payload log getting passed

```
{
  TableName: 'todos',
  Key: { task: 'see its  done' },
  UpdateExpression: 'set task = :task',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':task': 'edited' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made below common functions for the update, get, and create a table.use the same.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1",accessKeyId : process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY });
const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB()
const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const Dynamo = {
    async get(id, TableName) {
        const params = {
            TableName,
            Key: {
                id,
            },
        };

        const data = await documentClient.get(params).promise();

        if (!data || !data.Item) {
           throw Error(`There was an error fetching the data for ID of ${id} from ${TableName}`);
           
        }
        console.log(data);

        return data.Item;
    },
    async getall(TableName) {
        const params = {
            TableName: TableName,
          };

        const data = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();

        if (!data || !data.Item) {
            throw Error(`There was an error fetching the data for ID of ${ID} from ${TableName}`);
        }
        console.log(data);

        return data.Items;
    },
    async getMany(params) {
        const data = await documentClient.scan(params).promise();
        console.log(data);
        if (!data || !data.Items) {
            throw Error(`There was an error fetching the data`);
        }

        return data.Items;
    },

    async write(data, TableName) {
        console.log('write dynamo',data, TableName);
        if (!data.id) {
            throw Error('no ID on the data');
        }

        const params = {
            TableName,
            Item: data,
        };

        const res = await documentClient.put(params).promise();

        if (!res) {
            throw Error(`There was an error inserting ID of ${data.id} in table ${TableName}`);
        }
        console.log('res of write dynamo ',res);
        return data;
    },
    async createTable(TableName) {
    documentClient
    .scan({
            TableName: TableName,
        })
    .promise()
    .catch(error => {
  
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            dynamoDB
            .createTable({
              AttributeDefinitions: [
                {
                  AttributeName: "id",
                  AttributeType: "S",
                },
              ],
              KeySchema: [
                {
                  AttributeName: "id",
                  KeyType: "HASH",
                },
              ],
              BillingMode: "PAY_PER_REQUEST",
              TableName: TableName,
            })
            .promise()
            .then(data => console.log("Success!", data))
            .catch(console.error)
        })
      });

    },

};
module.exports = Dynamo;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the dbClient.update method, you are declaring the parameter ExpressionAttributeNames. It should be ExpressionAttributeValues. This is why the error message indicates that *expression attribute value used in expression is not defined*.

So you can try it changing the dbClient.update call in this way:

```
const updateDoc = await dbClient
  .update({
    TableName: payload.TableName,
    Key: payload.Key,
    UpdateExpression: payload.UpdateExpression,
    ExpressionAttributeValues:payload.ExpressionAttributeValues,
    ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW",
  })
  .promise();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here as you are setting 'ExpressionAttributeNames:', you have to set 'ExpressionAttributeValues' as well.